# import 3dsmax,maya to matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, computer-vision, maya, 3dsmax

I think it is difficult to create a 3d model of a botanical tree in matlab so that I want to create the tree using software such as 3dsmax, maya, etc and then import it to matlab. My ultimate purpose is to access to the tree's pose data.

My question is that is this possible to import 3dsmax, maya, etc data to Matlab environment?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can export your 3dMax/Maya models to [Wavefront.obj files](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavefront_.obj_file) objects(ex: convert .3ds file to .obj file)
 using [Meshlab](http://meshlab.sourceforge.net/).
Then
you could use [wavefront-obj-toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27982-wavefront-obj-toolbox) to import that WaveFront objects in to Matlab.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let's me try it.